# How to get selectedKey of sap.m.Select from outside?

Tags: sapui5

Having this select control:

```js
new Select("id", {
  items: {
    path: "/cards",
    template: new ListItem({
      key: "{Kunnr}",
      text: "{Descrip}"
    }),
  },
});
```

I need it be able to get the selected key of it, but not in the change event. I need it from outside (another function).

I have tried using the ID but I just get `undefined` as result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by accesing to the properties from outside using the sap core:

```
var myvar = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("marcas");
var selectedKey= myvar.getProperty('/cards/Kunnr');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a some information missing from your question, mostly around how `oSelectMarca` is added to your view. This makes a difference in how it's made available in your app. There are two places to get something by Id:

```
this.getView().byId('id');
sap.ui.getCore().byId('id');
```

You'll have to check which one it is... Another option is to add that model to your view instead of `oSelectMarca` in which case your view and your select can share data. But once again that depends on how you add the select to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where You need to use it You can do:

```
this.oSelectMarca = new sap.m.Select('id',{});
this.oSelectMarca.setModel(myModel);
```

or If You'll be using it in say another controller try:

```
sap.ui.getCore().oSelectMarca = new sap.m.Select('id',{});
sap.ui.getCore().oSelectMarca.setModel(myModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with two-way data binding in `selectedKey` which helps to keep the MV* pattern.

```js
new Select({
  selectedKey: "{/selectedCard}" // <-- It's TwoWay
  items: {
    path: "/cards",
    template: new ListItem({
        key: "{Kunnr}",
        text: "{Descrip}"
    }),
  },
});
```

I'm assuming that the default model is accessible across the application. Hence, as long as you can access that model, you can get the selected key by `myModel.getProperty("/selectedCard");`